# Grails 2.3.7 breaking changes

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

Hi after upgrading my grails app from 2.1 to 2.3.7 I get the following error on runApp:

```
2014-04-28 10:04:07,841 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager':
```

Are there any data source related breaking changes in 2.3.7

EDIT: Adding DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/pms_dev"
            logSql = true
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/pms_test"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/pms_prod"
        }
    }
}
```

JNDI Entries defined in Config.groovy:

```
grails.naming.entries = [
    'jdbc/pms_dev': [
        type: 'javax.sql.DataSource',
        auth: 'Container',
        description: 'Main datasource',

        url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER:1521:SCHEMA,
        username: "pms",
        password: "PASSWORD",
        driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",

        maxActive: "8",
        maxIdle: "4"
        ]

    ]
```

Comment: List of breaking changes is here: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html
Can't find anything relevant.

Comment: 2.2 changes: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html
Again nothing seems relevant.

Comment: Try running `grails clean-all` then re-compile. Also, it seems datasource related, so please post your `Datasource.groovy` file.

Comment: Problem persists after clean-all

Comment: It's to do with the JNDI stuff. You have to disable forking.

Comment: Why the down vote? I'm having exactly this error too.

Comment: Don't know. No down vote from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.fork = false
```

Also added to dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy

```
build "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4"
```